# String compression to refresh WS2811 RGB LEDs faster

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port, compression, led

I have the following problem. I am using WS2811 diodes, Arduino Due and node.js to my project. I want to stream video from a device connected to a node.js server and show it on array of diodes. Right now I am able to capture video from any device with browser and camera, change resolution of the video to this desired by me (15x10) and create String chain containing informations of all colors (R,G,B) of all diodes. I am sending it from node.js server to arduino though serial port with baud rate 115200. Unfortunately sending process it is too slow. I would like it to refresh the LED array at least 10 times per second. So I was wondering maybe to compress this string which I am sending to arduino, when it gets there decompress it, and set colors to diodes. Maybe you guys have some experience with similar project and advice me what to do.

For handling diodes I am using adafruit_neopixel library.

Comment: Let's do some math. You have 150 pixels @ 10Hz, that's 1500 pixels/second. One pixel needs 24 bits/pixel * 1.25µs/bit = 30µs/pixel = 0.00003s/pixel. 1500pixels/second*30µs/pixel = 45ms/second, i.e. 4.5%. So the controller will have to spend only 4.5% of its time sending data to the display and has 95.5% left for other things. That's the good news. The bad news is that while sending data to the LEDs the controller cannot do *anything* else or the timing will break, not even servicing the serial RX ISR. So either you synchronize the transmission of serial data to updating the display, or you'll

Comment: miss bytes on the µC's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would try to convert the video to a 16-bit encoding (like RGB565), or maybe even 8-bit, on your server.

Even at that low resolution I'm not certain the atmega328p is powerful enough to convert it back to 24-bit and send the data out to the display, but TIAS.  If it doesn't work, you might want to consider switching to a BeagleBone or RPi.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large areas of a similar colour, especially if you have dropped your bit depth to 16 or 8 bits as suggested in the previous answer, Run Length Encoding compression might be worth a try.

It's easy to implement it in a few lines of code:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding